# Database design for handling quiz site stats

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to create a quiz site and I'm not sure about how should I proceed with statistics. The site needs to track each users progress (which answer was answered how, how many time does it take to answer each question etc).

Should I create a new table (let's say 'statistics), and should I create a new row each time a user has finished a quiz? So, **statistics**:

- user_id
- quiz_id
- answers (in serialized form, because the amount of questions is variable)
- time_of_answer (same as above)
- points_for_each_answer (same as above)

Wouldn't this be too slow, if the admin wants to check some stats, let's say: how many users have correctly answered the question #2 under the 3rd quiz?

Comment: I'd swap `quiz_id` with `answer_id`, since presumably the answer implies the quiz (so statistics is linked to answer, which is linked to quiz). Then you can record answers individually, and avoid the serialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't serialize answers if you need them as a real entity - just give them a `quiz_id` foreign key so you know to which quiz they belong, use proper indexes, and everything will run smooth.

Comment: Under answers I meant the actual answers the user has given for each question.. so lets say there are 4 answers, then I need to store the corresponding numbers which answers were given: 2, 3, 1, 4 . What would be the best way to store those given answers, where the amount of answers can vary, because the amount of question under one quiz varies (from 3 to 10).

Sorry if my questions are a little lame :)

Comment: You need an `answers` table, with `answer_id` as PK, `quiz_id` as FK, `value` / `choice` / whatever as the real answer body. You don't have to care about amount then.